# I want create WordPress menu from scratch

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is my Code , I just want to same as it in my word-press menu.
I am using .but using this i am only getting parent menu not child.
if it's possible with walker menu then please help me.
I am using this code for get menu on front-end

PHP:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'container_class' => 'main-navigation'
    )
);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <li>
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                About Us
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="who-we-are.html">Who are we</a></li>
                <li><a href="core-value.html">Our Core Values</a></li>
                <li><a href="management-team.html">Management Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="customer-partner.html">Clients &amp; Partners</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="about-us-img"></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Service Offering
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="service-offer dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <i class="by-industry"></i><h3>By Industry</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="manufacturing .html">Manufacturing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="healthcare .html">Healthcare</a></li>
                        <li><a href="retail.html">Retail</a></li>
                        <li><a href="consumer-durables.html">Consumer Durables</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logistics.html">Logistics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ites-bpo-kpo.html">ITES (BPO/KPO)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ecommerce .html">E-Commerce</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><i class="by-function"></i><h3>By Function</h3>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="sales.html">Sales</a></li>
                <li><a href="marketing.html">Marketing</a></li>
                <li><a href="supply-chain.html">Supply Chain</a></li>
                <li><a href="finance.html">Finance</a></li>
                <li><a href="hr.html">HR</a></li>
                </ul>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="by-tech"></i><h3>By Technology</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="qlikview.html">Qlikview</a></li>
                        <li><a href="qliksense.html">QlikSense</a></li>
                        <li><a href="msbi.html">MSBI</a></li>
                        <li><a href="dot-net.html">.Net</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sharepoint.html">SharePoint</a></li>
                        <li><a href="middleware-api.html">Middleware/API</a></li>
                        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="by-business"></i><h3>By Line of Business</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="analytics.html">Analytics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="application-development.html">Application Development</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="drop-resourse">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Resources
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="resourse-menu">
                <li><a href="case-studies.html">Case Studies</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.blog.polestarllp.com/">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="press-release.html">Press Releases</a></li>
                <li><a href="methodology.html">Methodology</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="resourse-img"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="drop-career">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Career
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="career-menu">
                <li><a href="job-opening.html">Job Opening</a></li>
                <li><a href="life-at-polestar.html">Life@Polestar</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="career-img"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="drop-conatct">
            <a href="contact-us.html">
                Contact Us
            </a>


        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When you add menu item into wordpress from admin panel, You can see "Screen option" label on top right corner. After click on that label, you just checked option "CSS Classes". Using this setting you will add class into your menu item as per your scratch menu.

Comment: thanks , this is awesome, here is a link, http://polestarllp.com/

Comment: You can set your menu like below:
<?php  wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Nav 1' )); ?>
<div>image</div>
<?php  wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Nav 2' )); ?>
<div>image</div>
<div>image</div>
<?php  wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Nav 3' )); ?>
<div>image</div>
<?php  wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Nav 4' )); ?>

Comment: I have to create 4 menu in functions.php and after that call one by one , please clear me

Comment: No you need to first set your menu structure into your mind then after use this kind of code for display your menu as per scratch and if you can purchase plugin then you can use "Mega Main Menu - WordPress Menu Plugin" which is same as per your requirement.

Comment: ok one last question how can upload image with  menu

Comment: You can not upload image with menu but according to above code you can set image as per your need like:
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Nav 2' )); ?> <div>image</div>

Comment: Not sure but i don't think. i suggest above code is ok for you.

Comment: can we use walker menu

Comment: Yes, you can try. May it's work but i think it's tricky not sure.

Comment: yes but we have to try this , it's very neccessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you're getting the top-level nav-items, but not the drop-down / sub-menus? If so, you can add the "depth" parameter to your wp_nav_menu function:

```
    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary',
            'container_class' => 'main-navigation',
            'depth' => 2
        )
    );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/